# How to check if string of group in pandas is contained in another string of the same group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this sample of dataframe

```
| identifier    | span           | matched_string |
| --------      | -------------- | ------         | 
| occupation    | [0,12]         | general manager| 
| occupation    | [0,7]          | manager        |
| time schedule | [13,14]        | "0-5"          |
| occupation    | [0,12].        | clerk          |
```

I want to group the df by identifier and then only keep the rows where a matched string is contained in another matched string of the same group and is the longer string. In this case manager is contained in general manager. Also I want to only keep the row if the matched string lays in the same span as the other matched string.

In the end the df should look like this:

```
  | identifier   | span           | matched_string |
  | --------     | -------------- | ------         |
  | occupation   | [0,12]         | general manager| 
  | time schedule| [13,14]        | "0-5"          |
  | occupation   | [0,12]         | clerk          |
```

In order to access the matches I have this code:

```
ka = testa.groupby(["identifier"])
    
for name, group in ka:
      for index, row in group.iterrows(): 
            for i in group['matched_string'].values:
                for j in group['matched_string'].values:
                    for k in group['span_info'].values:
                        for l in group['span_info'].values:
                            if i != j and k != l:
                                for m in list(range(k[0],k[1])):
                                    if m in list(range(l[0], l[1])) and i in j:
                                       max(i, j, key=len)
```

Is there smarter way to do this? Also does someone have an idea on how I can keep rows where the strings dont contain one another as eg time schedule from the example table?

Btw sorry for the bad format of the table but somehow I could not post the question unless it was formatted as code... Idk why

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by subdividing the for loops into functions and let them return True. Then I dropped those rows by index where both functions returned True.

This is my solution:

```
testa = df.groupby(["job_title_index", "identifier"])

#check if string matches are contained in the same span
def same_span(row, row2):
    span_info = row['span_info']
    span_info2 = row2['span_info']
    if span_info != span_info2:
        #check if any number in range of span_info lays in another range(span_info[0], span_info[1])
        for i in range(span_info[0], span_info[1]):
            if i in range(span_info2[0], span_info2[1]):
                return True

#check if same matched_string
def matched_string_check(row, row2):
    if row['matched_string'] in row2['matched_string'] and row['matched_string'] != row2['matched_string']:
        return True

for name, group in testa:
    for index, row in group.iterrows():
        for index2, row2 in group.iterrows():
            if matched_string_check(row,row2) and same_span(row,row2):
                if max(row["matched_string"],row2["matched_string"],key=len) == row["matched_string"]:
                    df.drop(index2, inplace=True)
                else:
                    df.drop(index, inplace=True)
```